Are there reference cycles or other unreachable objects in Python 3 that cannot be destroyed by the garbage collector?
When the Python garbage collector runs (at a sufficiently high generation) it will find cycles of unreachable objects, meaning that they can't be accessed anymore, but the reference count will never go to 0 either.
I just learned that in Python up to 3.3, if the objects implemented a custom __del__, it would not be able to destroy them because it cannot know a safe order in which to call the __del__ of the objects:
class X(object):
    def __init__(self, ref=None):
        self.ref = ref
    def __del__(self):
        print("destroyed")
        return None

x = X()
y = X(x)
x.ref = y
x = y = None
import gc
gc.collect() # make sure the garbage collector runs
len(gc.garbage)

In Python 2.7, the output is
2

In Python 3.10 it is
destroyed
destroyed
0

The problem of cycles involving custom __del__ functions was solved following PEP-442. My question is if there are other situations in which unreachable Python objects may not be collected, either in Python 2 or in Python 3.

Python 2 is no longer supported, don't waste your brain power on it...
